# Cannot get vue-router to work with webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-elixir, vue-router

I'm trying to get vue-router to work without success and it got me quite angry after a while since i don't see any issue.

I'm using webpack via Elixir in Laravel, which has gulpfile like this:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

elixir(mix => {
mix.sass('app.scss')
   .webpack('app.js');
});
```

Into my app.js file I'm "compiling" following code

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

And when I call in browser console

```
new VueRouter({})
```

I got an error saying VueRouter is undefined. Why? The vue-resource is even in the app.js.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

thats okay cause you didnt bind VueRouter to the `window` object as you did with `window.Vue = require('vue');`

But usually you dont need the Router in the `window`
Do it in your app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
window.Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: {
    {path: '', component: require('./components/MyComponent.vue')},
    {path: '/dash', component: require('./components/Dash.vue')},
  }
});

var AppComponent = require('./components/App.vue');

/* eslint-disable no-new */
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(AppComponent),
});
```

Comment: So what's the solution? You're saying I should bind it this way `window.Vue.use(VueRouter)`? Because if Vue is not binded to window, it doesn't work at all...

Comment: Can you spare few minutes on skype or hangout? It still doesn't go for me.